# Meaning of the object arising from application of contravariant derivative on a scalar field

Tags: calculus, tensors

The contravariant derivative operator can be defined by the action of contravariant metric tensor on the covariant derivative:

$$ Z^{ij} \nabla_i = \nabla^j$$

And, I know that applying the contravariant derivative on an invariant scalar field gives me it's gradient:

$$ \nabla^iF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial Z^j} Z^{ij}$$

Now, applying this to the covariant metric tensor to both sides

$$ \nabla_k F= Z_{ik} \nabla^iF = \frac{\partial  F}{\partial Z^j} Z^{ij} Z_{ik}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial Z^k}$$

Does this new object have any interpretation? I know it's not an invariant but it seems to agree with the regular gradient in cartesian coordinates.

The motivation on why I am asking this question is that I have been going over Pavel Grinfelds tensor calculus book, and in it Grinfeld had stated invariants i.e: Tensors are purely geometric objects (meaning they have some sort of interpetation). So, I'm trying to ponder if non invariants have no geometric meaning or not.

Comment: Be careful with your indices.... Your expression for the gradient can't quite be right. The left side has one lower $i$ index and the right side has a dummy index and an upper $i$ index.

Comment: I took it from pg-145, eqtn 9.16 of Pavel's Tensor calculus book

Comment: We must have different editions of his book. The 2013 edition has pg-145 discussing equations number 9.63-9.70 with a guest appearance of 9.61. In this edition, equation 9.69 is clearly $$ \nabla^i F = Z^{ij} \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial Z^j} $$

Comment: Oh jeez I screwed up. You are right, I'll fix it. I also miswrote 9.69 as 9.16 

Comment: It happens to everyone! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The covariant derivative of an object which is invariant (a scalar, vector, higher order tensor, etc) will just yield the object's partial derivative. Observe that

$$ \nabla_i F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial z^i}  $$

implying that the object in "invariant form" would be given as

$$ \nabla_i F  \vec{Z}^{\:i} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial z^i} \vec{Z}^{\:i} \text{ .}$$

This is the invariant gradient object as written as a differential 1-form. If we wish to express it as a classical gradient, then it must be a "physical (tangent) vector". We can of course transform a 1-form to it's associated tangent vector as

$$ (\nabla F)^k = Z^{k\ell} \: \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z^\ell} $$

$$ \implies(\nabla F)^k \vec{Z}_k = Z^{k\ell} \: \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z^\ell}\vec{Z}_k \text{ .} $$

The only thing that we would achieve by using a contravariant derivative instead is that

$$ \nabla^j F = Z^{ij}\nabla_i F = Z^{ij}\frac{\partial F}{\partial z^i}  $$

would already have the form of a once covariant tensor

$$ \nabla^j F \vec{Z}_j = Z^{ij}\frac{\partial F}{\partial z^i} \vec{Z}_j $$

which is exactly the tangent vector which corresponds with the gradient.

Comment: where do these differential form things come from? I have a vague understanding of them but I thought they were disjoint from tensor approach to working with manifolds. I have found no mention of them in Pavel's book either (till where I read at least)

Comment: @Buraian Exterior calculus is intrinsically tied into the tensor calculus of manifolds. In fact, when Pavel writes $ \vec{Z}^{\: k} $ he really means the contravariant basis vector. This contravariant basis is a basis of the dual space to the tangent vectors $\vec{V} = V^k \vec{Z}_{k} $.  We can go as far as to say the object he calls $ \vec{Z}^{\: k}$ is defined as the functional $dz^k$.

Comment: Ah dang it, more to learn before I understand. If you don't mind could you explain how exactly it's intrinsically tied? I think I'll return to this answer after reading a more technical book which involves forms as well

Comment: @Buraian If $T_p M$ is the tangent vector space at point $p$ on a manifold $M$, then the dual space $T_p^{\: *} M$ is the space of all linear functionals $\alpha : T_p M \to \mathbb{R}$. Any "covariant vector" in Pavel's book can be thought of as a linear functional that operates on contravariant vectors 
$$\alpha(\vec{V})=a_k\vec{Z}^{\:k}(v^j\vec{Z}_j)=a_kv^j\delta^k_j=a_kv^k$$ where it is important to note that we have implicitly chosen $\vec{Z}^{\:k}\vec{Z}_j=\delta_j^k$ to define our dual basis. These "covariant vectors" are differential one-forms. Does this help any?

Comment: So, the covariant basis can't be expressede in regular basis? They are a linear map after all

Comment: @Buraian yes, they are (like all tensors) a linear map. But why should this mean that they don't have a basis? All tensors are linear maps and they certainly have the covariant and contravariant bases. Polynomials form a vector space as well with the basis $(x^0,x^1,x^2,\dots)$.

Comment: Oh, right. I am a bit tripped up by the big picture of all this but I guess it will come with time.